# How to upload file in AWS S3 with django app?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-handling

I am facing a problem uploading the user profile picture. Now when I create a user in Django admin and upload a file from the admin dashboard it works correctly and no errors. It goes to my AWS S3 bucket as it should go, but this is obviously not feasible, I have been looking for the solution for 3 to 4 days but no success or any satisfactory results. I obviously won't be providing the dashboard access to the user. The database used is MongoDB, with a database engine as djongo.

Here is my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'profileupload',
    's3direct',
    'storages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'MY_SPECIAL_KEY'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MY_SPECIAL_KEY_NAME'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'S3_BUCKET'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import signup_form
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', signup_form, name='signup'),
]
```

My models.py

```
class profile(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    profile_username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    profile_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    profile_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    profile_create_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    profile_dob = models.DateField()
    profile_password = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.profile_username)
```

My views.py

```
def signup_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('profile_username') and request.POST.get('profile_name') and request.POST.get('profile_email') and request.POST.get('profile_dob') and request.POST.get('profile_password') and request.POST.get('profile_picture'):
            pr = profile()
            pr.profile_username = request.POST.get('profile_username')
            pr.profile_name = request.POST.get('profile_name')
            pr.profile_email = request.POST.get('profile_email')
            pr.profile_password = request.POST.get('profile_password')
            pr.profile_dob = request.POST.get('profile_dob')
            pr.profile_picture = request.POST.get('profile_picture')
            try:
                pr.save()
                print('setProfile success')
                return redirect('index.html')
            except Exception as e:
                return render(request, 'signup.html')
            return render(request, 'signup.html') 
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

My Sign up Form 'signup.html'

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <label>USERNAME</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="profile_username" required/>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label>NAME</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="profile_name" required/>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label>EMAIL</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="" name="profile_email" required/>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="" name="profile_password" required/>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label>DOB</label>
        <input type="date" placeholder="" name="profile_dob" required/>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label>Profile Picture</label>
        <input type="file" placeholder="" name="profile_picture" required/>
    </div><br>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<a href="/">Home</a>
{% endblock content %}
```

Also, I want to change the name of the uploaded file, the file which is uploaded by Django admin takes the file name as it is, but when I will expose this app to the public the file name must be proper to avoid overwritten or having the same file multiple times

Comment: Hey, I'm facing a similar issue and have been looking for a working solution past 1 week. Have you found out the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I got some notion of applying the wrong access keys and taking wrong inputs in views.py

**First of all taking correct inputs in views.py**

```
pr.profile_picture = request.POST.get('profile_picture')
```

instead of using the above, the following would help:

```
pr.profile_picture  = request.FILES["profile_picture"]
```

also, when I use the above with *single inverted commas* it won't work, so keep that in mind.

**Uploading the file to S3**

Now there will be some other ways to do this but changing the name of the file at the same time.

I made another file specially to handle images and changing the name of the file.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id= 'secret sauce',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'secret sauce'
)

class image():
    def UploadImage(name,image):
        filename = name+'_picture.jpg'
        imagedata = image
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        try:
            object = s3.Object('bucket sauce', filename)
            object.put(ACL='public-read',Body=imagedata,Key=filename)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            return e
```

above method is called in views.py

```
ret = image.UploadImage(pr.profile_username,pr.profile_picture)
```

put it in the try block to avoid errors.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, one way is by directly using the `boto3` library.

Another way is by using the `save` functionality of `django-storages` (which also uses `boto3` in the background).

- Reference: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

### If there is only 1 bucket:

settings.py

```
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "storages",
    ...
]

...


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my-access-key-id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my-secret-access-key'
# Depending on the AWS account used, you might also need to declare AWS_SESSION_TOKEN as an environment variable

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket'

...
```

views.py

```
from io import BytesIO

from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view(('GET',))
def save_file(request):
    file_name = "toguro.txt"
    file_content = b"I have my full 100% power now!"
    file_content_io = BytesIO(file_content)

    default_storage.save(file_name, file_content_io)

    return Response({"message": "File successfully saved"})
```

### If there are many buckets:

settings.py

```
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "storages",
    ...
]

...

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my-access-key-id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my-secret-access-key'
# Depending on the AWS account used, you might also need to declare AWS_SESSION_TOKEN as an environment variable

...
```

views.py

```
from io import BytesIO

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


# For a clear separation-of-concern, you should consider placing this code to its appropriate place
class MyStorage1(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = 'my-bucket-1'


class MyStorage2(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = 'my-bucket-2'


@api_view(('GET',))
def save_file(request):
    file_name_1 = "toguro.txt"
    file_name_2 = "sensui.txt"
    file_content_1 = b"I have my full 100% power now!"
    file_content_2 = b"I will release the S-Class demons!"
    file_content_io_1 = BytesIO(file_content_1)
    file_content_io_2 = BytesIO(file_content_2)

    storage1 = MyStorage1()
    storage2 = MyStorage2()
    storage1.save(file_name_1, file_content_io_1)
    storage2.save(file_name_2, file_content_io_2)

    return Response({"message": "File successfully saved"})
```